# Collision Detection in java

Tags: java, collision-detection, lwjgl

I have some questions on collision detection. I am using LWJGL for my game in java. I have no experience in this subject and have been following the thin matrix OpenGL tutorials for the core of the game. I have experience in html, css, c++ and, of course, java.
I have been searching all over the web and have not found anything useful.

What is the simplest way to implement 3D collision detection in my games?

Comment: I am trying to get his question reopened by editing the question. Hope that's ok.

Comment: ok thanks for the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a 3d engine that recognizes collision for you like jMonkey. jMonkey can use LWJGL. There is an awesome tutorial here : http://wiki.jmonkeyengine.org/doku.php/jme3:beginner:hello_collision

If you want to roll your own like I do, I create a hash of the 3d points in space. If another object has the same hash it has near collision.

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class App {
    public static int hash(float x, float y, float z) {
        double hash = (((x * 31) + (y * 37) + (z * 41)));//31,37 and 41 are prime numbers
        return (int) (hash);//multiplying the hash by 1000 for example may increase the accuracy significantly. Depends on the size of your space
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (float count = 0; count < 2; count += 0.01) {
            out.println(hash(0, 0, count));
        }
    }

}
```

As you can see the hashes in the output show close collision as count increments by 0.01.

```
0
0
0
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
4
4
4
5
5
6
6
6
```

You can modify the prime numbers for higher accuracy.

Comment: thanks this is great